# Company outsourced testing; how can we encourage programmers to stop overly relying on testers?

Tags: testing, communication, outsourcing

A friend of mine is working in a 200-employee company. The company's business has nothing to do with IT, but they do have an IT department to work, among others, on their website, used by the customers.

The website started with a core idea that programmers have to test the application themselves using automated testing. However, it quickly started to be problematic, as programmers were spending too much time writing functional tests with [Selenium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29) (and later [Cypress.io](https://www.cypress.io/)) trying to deal with either complicated interactions, such as drag and drop or file uploads, or trying to figure out why the tests randomly fail. For a while, more than 25% of the time was spent on those tests; moreover, most programmers were pissed off by those tests, as they wanted to produce actual value, not try to figure out why the tests would randomly fail.

Two years ago, it was decided to pay a company from Bulgaria to do the functional, interface-level tests manually. Things went well, as such testing was pretty inexpensive. Overall, programmers were delivering features faster, with fewer regressions, and everyone was happy.

However, over time, programmers started to be overconfident. They would write fewer integration or even unit tests, and would sometimes mark features as done without even actually checked if they work in a browser: since testers will catch the mistakes, why bother? This creates two problems: (1) it takes more time to solve the issues when they are discovered by testers a few days ago (compared to when they are discovered within minutes by programmers themselves) and (2) the overall cost of the outsourced testers grows constantly.

Recently, the team lead tries to change this behavior by:

- Measuring, per person, how many tickets are reopened by the testers (and sharing the results to the whole team).
- Giving congratulation to the persons who performed the best, i.e. those who have the least tickets being reopened.
- Spend time pair programming with those who performed the worst, trying to understand why are they so reluctant to test their code, and showing them that it's not that difficult.
- Explaining that it's much faster to solve a problem right now, than to wait for several days until the feature gets tested.
- Explaining that testers do system tests only, and the lack of unit tests make it difficult to pinpoint the exact location of the problem.

However, it doesn't work:

- The metrics are not always relevant. One may work on an unclear or complex ticket which gets reopened several times by the testers because of the edge cases, and a colleague may meanwhile work on a ticket which is so straightforward that there is absolutely no chance to introduce any regression.
- Programmers are reluctant to test code, because (1) they find it just boring, and because (2) if they don't test code, it *looks like* they deliver the feature faster.
- They also don't see why fixing a problem days after developing a feature would be a problem. They understand the theory, but they don't *feel* it in practice. Also, they believe that even if it would take a bit longer, it's still cheaper for the company to pay inexpensive outsourced testers rather than spend programmers' time on tests. Telling them repeatedly that this is not the case has no effect.
- As for system vs. unit testing, programmers reply that they don't spend that much time finding the exact location of a problem reported by a tester anyway (which seems to be actually true).

What else can be done to encourage programmers to stop overly rely on testers?

Comment: Metrics are like s thermometer.  They are an unambiguous measure of something.  Just because a measurement is high (relative to your threshold) doesn't mean something is wrong, but it does mean it bears further scrutiny.

Comment: Are the programmers being more careless because there are testers or because they are under the gun to produce more code quickly? Just from your description of your problem and the way you speak about the developers, I would never work for that company. It sounds like you have managers that are not fit to deal with engineers.

Comment: Fire the testers.

Comment: Programmers that thing automated testing aren't providing "actual value" aren't programmers I want on my team.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch Almost absolutely the opposite on metrics.  Metrics can and always are gamed, and they never measure the right thing.  Who had the most tickets reopened?  Absolutely useless-  it generally boils down to who has the most tickets, or who's tickets were most ambiguously defined.  Metrics work well when the thing you measure is what you actually care about (like how long a request takes, and even then you need to understand p90 vs avg).  Metrics are a HUGE NEGATIVE when they try to measure something indirectly like this. Using something like this is a sign management is clueless

Comment: @corsiKa - if you think automated testing just magically provides value by existing, you actually have no idea what you're talking about. Tests are just like documentation. You can have million test cases, or million pages of documentation, and if they are not good, they provide negative value.

Comment: "more than 25% of the time was spent on those tests" - Is that a lot? By LOC, a library with good test coverage may be 80% tests.

Comment: This entire story is one management failure followed by another designed to fix the previous. If your developers cannot test the product because of complex interactions **then users cannot use the product because of complex interactions**. The failure of developers to write understandable, robust tests **was a gift that you squandered** because **it was signal about vital customer-impacting issues that you ignored**.  Your best bet would be to obtain new management who understand the signals produced by test failures and how to react to achieve customer value.

Comment: Supporting @EricLippert, The best way to get new management maybe to shift jobs, or be ready to! The art of management can be difficult for growing companies because the styles and techniques need to adapt to the scale of the organisation (there will be a Conway's law corollary for it)

Comment: @PhilipOakley, it's not always just styles and techniques. The attitude of the vast majority of managers in the economy is that business administration is something anybody can do, and they put up with the savants in IT (and their vast timewasting) because they're still cheaper overall than an army of clerks. The absence of standards in the quality of administration - save perhaps nowadays the focus on data protection - means that very frequently there are short-term gains from poor administration, and companies trying to optimise profit get stuck in so-called "local maxima" of bad practices.

Comment: The specific problem of not understanding test signals is symptomatic of an even larger management problem: not understanding what testing is for in the first place. QAs job is not to test that the product works as designed. **QAs job is to ensure a quality product by acting as empowered advocates for the customer to set a quality bar and ensure that it is met**. Joel Spolsky once pointed out that if you make fine chocolate, you outsource the box, not the chocolate. Empowering a team to act on behalf of your customers to ensure a quality product *is the chocolate*; don't outsource it!

Comment: @DavorŽdralo There is no such thing as magic, only very patient rabbits. Of course it does not magically provide value. Like so many things that produce value for developers, it must be taught. But if it is not learned once taught, it's time to find developers who take it seriously. Code standards, code reviews, change management, these things also don't magically provide value either, and can even provide the negative value you so fear. Should we shy away from those just because they might be done wrong? Surely not.

Comment: Like some other commenters, I'm curious about that initial >25% figure for "the time... spent on those tests". If that was time spent "writing functional tests with Selenium (and later Cypress.io) trying to deal with either complicated interactions, such as drag and drop or file uploads", then it sounds like the programmers should've been writing more low-level UNIT tests for their own code, rather than trying to wrestle unproven code into an integration testing framework where — and, this shouldn't have been a surprise — the untested units would cause random failures. `exit(ETOOHIGHLEVEL)`

Comment: @corsiKa: where does that quote (about rabbits) come from?!

Comment: Can you clarify *"4. Explaining that it's much faster [for whom?] to solve a problem right now, than to wait for several days until the feature gets tested."* I completely don't understand what that's supposed to mean. Programmers now ship bad untested code as fast as they can write it, then there's a time-lag before failing tests come back from the testers, then they fix the code? What does "solve a problem" mean? Fix bad code to make a testcase or two work, even if the other 95% fail? Or actually fix up the code to pass *all* tests and spec? ...

Comment: ...I think your company is creating (through garbage 'micro-task-related' metrics) the illusion of "solving" lots of micro-problems. Once management adopts a fake metric of productivity like that, you're doomed (unless you can educate them, but they've bought into the cost-savings; or until quality gets so bad that the end-customer fires them).

Comment: @smci it is my own invention

Answer (score 66, accepted):

It seems to me there is a contradiction in policy here.

On the one hand, the firm has outsourced testing because it consumed programmers' time excessively, and could be done more cheaply by others.

Now, they complain that the programmers are relying on the testers, and should be doing more testing themselves up front.

I can understand from a management point of view that there is perceived to be a happy medium, but in reality the programmers are not engaging in a close analysis, on a case-by-case basis, of how much testing they do themselves and how much they outsource.

To attempt to do so would consume too much time and intellectual effort, and likely without producing accurate results. How would a programmer go about estimating how many bugs a particular piece of code has, and then weighing up the economic benefit of spending his own time searching for them versus letting the testers search for them? It's an absurdity.

Instead programmers are following rules of thumb. Previously the rule was to test extensively. Now the rule is to save precious programmer time, get more code out the door, and leave testing to testers (who are thought to be ten-a-penny).

It's no answer to seek a happy medium, because in practice what will happen is that the anal-retentives will return to spending 25% of their time testing, and the cowboys will continue throwing low-quality code out the door, and personality traits like conscientiousness and attention to detail (or lack thereof) will predominate over the judgment. If management try to harass both types to get them to conform more closely to an average which is perceived to be economically ideal, both will probably just end up feeling harassed.

I would also remark in passing, that the 25% of time which was spent testing to begin with, does not strike me as excessive.

Comment: Actually running the code to see if it works isn't a "happy medium" it's a minimum of effort expected from competent developers.  Some devs apparently aren't even doing that.

Comment: @DaveG, I don't know whether the problem is so bad that the code doesn't work under any circumstances, and any running would result in a crash or obvious dysfunction. I assume things are a bit more subtle than that, in the typical case.

Comment: From the OP: "they would write less integration or even unit tests, and would sometimes mark features as done **without even actually checked if they work in a browser**:"

Comment: @DaveG, I took that to be illustrative of the cavalier attitude to testing that has emerged. Otherwise it would be most surprising if the solution were that simple.

Comment: @DaveG: Some bulky applications exist that cannot be simply spun up for a debug session. From experience, it can be a reliance on services/workers/queues, a complicated UI with no quickly accessible or transparent test data, ... (I agree these are problems, btw) I'm not saying that makes it allright, developers obviously need to to a basic inspection; but if the testing process is bulky and fidgety, and the company explicitly communicates that no time shall be wasted on testing; then the bulky and fidgety testing work is logically going to be the first that gets passed to the external testers.

Comment: CAnnot follow the initial logic in this, there is a difference between unit tests and happy path testing and manual QA. But it might hint at an answer, in that the programmers don't know the difference either...

Comment: @Flater You're making up a situation that doesn't fit the post.  Sure, sometimes testing in the exact product environment can be difficult.  Read the post.  The programmers used to do all the testing.  Clearly they have a test environment.  Some devs have slacked off and aren't testing in the browser.  Nothing that would lead anyone to conclude that this is due to a missing test environment.

Comment: feels like you're overestimating the difficulty of finding a happy medium. could easily set a bar for devs: unit test coverage, difference between shipping code that literally doesn't work vs code that has reasonable bugs, etc

Comment: @DaveG: I didn't say there is a missing test environment. I was pointing out that some codebases are less than trivial to test (for _whatever_ reason that may be) which is going to negatively impact developers testing trivialities. That doesn't excuse it, but it does mitigate it when you factor in human behavior. Doubly so in a company where there has been explicit talk about developers not wasting time on testing. A laborious test process to test a triviality is the first thing that meets the "wasted time on testing" standard - it's not too far-fetched to understand why devs skip these.

Comment: @aw04, the "happy medium" to which I refer is merely a management illusion, and I devote a significant part of my answer to explaining why it's pie in the sky. There was a working bar: the programmers spent 25% of their time on tests. Management abolished that to outsource and save money, and despite being chastised by the results, have not reverted to established patterns, and even the OP employs the language that testing is something other than "delivering features". This is not a programmer problem, it's a management attitude problem as usual.

Comment: You sum up the situation perfectly, but dont provide a clear answer. You can see how both the devs and testers could fall into a happy routine,  charging for their retrospetive jobs, passing bug tickets back and forth without actually producing working features. Should devs do all testing? Should the teams be joined? Should the testers create automated tests that must be made to pass? What?

Comment: @Ewan, the answer is to resolve the contradiction in policy, between the company outsourcing all their testing function to a low-rate contractor, and then complaining that bugs are not being caught internally - and moreover, complaining that the programmers have acquired bad attitudes to testing and catching bugs early! As for work resonating unproductively between dev and tester, that's the nature of the beast when a division of labour occurs across management boundaries - is it any different from the inefficiencies of agile, where work bounces back and forth between dev and client?

Comment: 25% does not strike me as sufficient.

Answer (score 36):

Bottom line: **this is a cultural problem.**

I come from the viewpoint that competent programmers at least write unit tests for the more complex parts of their code.  The problem is not everyone shares my viewpoint.  I've known people who have been developing code longer than I've been alive and they also test their code — just not necessarily with automated testing.  There are a number of things in software development that are too simple to test so those tests hold no real value.

That said, there are different levels of testing with different percentages of random failures that can happen.  From a management perspective, you have to understand where you gain value.

- **Unit tests:** check implementation details and error handling as close to the logic as possible.
- **Integration tests:** check that system specifications are working correctly
- **User Interface tests**: check that the application behaves according to the requirements

Unsurprisingly, the further you get away from the individual code units, the more brittle your tests become.  The more pieces you have that must work together, the more chances that something will intermittently go wrong.  What that means is that the closer to the unit test you can catch problems the more reliable and valuable those tests are.

**Cost of Automation**

Automation costs time.  Time costs money.  It takes longer to write automated tests than it does to manually test a feature.  However, each time that automated test is run, it runs in a fraction of the time of manual testing.  From a management standpoint, you want to make sure you have a good return on your investment.  I highly recommend that the highest risk code — if it breaks the application is useless — should have automated tests to ensure that you catch regressions (broken code) as soon as they occur.  If the unit tests don't pass, the developer can't push their code.

In general it does help to have some guidelines, and a means of ensuring high risk code is covered.

- Unit tests should have *at least* 25% coverage.  (I personally prefer higher, but for a team with no unit tests this is a good place to start)
- Unit and integration tests should be prioritized on high risk code first.
- **Definition of Done** needs to have one or both requirements:

  - Code peer review (Pull requests are a great way to organize these)
  - Unit test coverage meets minimum criteria

**Cost of Manual Testing**

Manual testing costs time.  Time costs money.  While it is faster to manually test a feature one time, it takes the same amount of time to test the feature each time.  You want to keep testing finished features to protect from regressions.  Regressions are functionality in your application that used to work that don't any more.

The hidden cost of manual testing is that testers are people, and sometimes people skip tests on accident.  If you thought writing automated tests was tedious, try testing the same features with all the button clicks time after time.

**Optimizing your investment**

Here's where both management and development have to be on the same page.  If quality is important to the company, then the company has to be willing to invest in quality.  If quality is not important, then just do away with testing.  Your users will complain, and you may or may not be embarrassed by the problems they complain about.  That said, if the application is mission critical, then quality *should* be important.

- Automate testing high risk code

  - Risk can be high due to the complexity of the solution
  - Risk can be high due to how necessary the feature is
  - Risk can be high due to the high number of dependencies on the code
- Don't write tests for code that is too simple to fail (like getters and setters)
- Manually test things that are too complicated to test automatically (like drag/drop)
- Invest in simplicity

  - A requirement on its own might be simple enough, but may conflict with other requirements.
  - Be ready to remove features so the application serves current needs.
- Define "done" so it is clear and unambiguous

  - When the work that needs to be done is unclear, then developers and testers have different opinions on what's right.
  - A few more minutes in a meeting with three people can save days of work and rework because of differing definitions of done.

**Summary**

The company culture is currently in a no-win situation.  Culture changes are easier when management has buy-in.  It's also easier when the team introduces disciplines that help them be more effective.  To that end, I would prioritize Defining Done before prioritizing anything to do with how tests are performed.

It's great that you are collecting metrics.  It's not great how those metrics are currently being used.  A better way is to look at the trends on the metrics as you introduce more structure in how your team develops software.  For example, if time to completion is improved and number of test failures are down because you spend more time defining what needs to be done, then that is a win.  If you increase your automated test coverage to 50% and don't see any improvement in the number of test failures then maybe 25% is good enough.

Software development is a team activity.  The more you work together as a team, the better everyone's attitude will become.  The more your team is set up for success, the more your team will experience success.

Comment: Not sure if this is covered by `Risk can be high due to how necessary the feature is`, but i'd also add that risk can be high due to an elevated number of users that depend on the feature, or an elevated number of processes that are affected by/related to the feature

Comment: That's what the second bullet there says.  I.e. how necessary the feature is.  I will add another bullet for the integration piece though.

Comment: Great answer, but I think it should be expanded by pointing out the fact that a culture is company wide. You can't change culture in your department only. In this case I have the impression the dev team is seen as feature machine and not enough time is spent with the developer and stakeholder to discover the problem and in that way gain a shared sense of responsibility.

Answer (score 19):

Okay, we all share the common goal of protecting and defending developers but there are some things in your question that make me somewhat uncomfortable...

> They also don't see why fixing a problem days after developing a
>   feature would be a problem. They understand the theory, but they don't
>   feel it in practice.

I am sorry to break the news, but experienced programmers **do feel the value of catching a bug early in practice**.

> As for system vs. unit testing, programmers reply that they don't
>   spend that much time finding the exact location of a problem reported
>   by a tester anyway (which seems to be actually true).

This is textbook *defensive talk* (smells somewhat passive-aggressive). And of course it's true....until you put it in perspective. You can ask the programmers... do they use bookmarks in their browsers? Do they home-page a search engine? Do they use alt+tab to switch between applications/windows? All these things are pitiful excuses of productivity gains... that is if you do them **ONCE**. When you do it **all the time**, those few seconds gained easily sum up to countless man-days of productivity. It takes your programmers what, 1 minute to find the source of a problem reported by the tester? That's the time they **felt**. The actual time includes the time of the tester, the time to prepare the report/file the ticket, the time potentially spent in communicating the details **and** the time to close the ticket/report it as solved. And time is money, right?

Think of this like forgetting to buy milk when you go buy food. While you're IN the store, it's 1 minute of walking. When you are at home, it's exponentially more. Now, to put it in perspective, this is how 1 minute of felt time translates to ~30 minutes of actual trouble for all involved (though it is probably far more in reality). If management knew that proper testing could save the company some 30x the time occasionally spent given the current situation, how would they feel?

Furthermore...

> For a while, more than 25% of the time was spent on those tests;
>   moreover, most programmers were pissed off by those tests, as they
>   wanted to produce actual value, not try to figure out why the test
>   would randomly fail.

Again, I am sorry to break the news, but experienced programmers understand that **there is actual value in tests** plus 25% of the time is actually not that bad a percentage. Good tests are worth their length in gold! Also, **tests don't randomly fail**, at least not as often as this bold statement would have you think. Not **good** tests, at least, so the quality of the tests is also one thing that will have to be seriously considered. Think about the [CE mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CE_marking), for example, which is all about testing! Do the programmers equally disagree that it does add actual value to products?

The actual trouble with this last quoted OP statement, however, is that it seems to hint that management has actually **taken advice from the programmers** to outsource testing, or at least been affected by the programmers' aversion to testing, unlike how other answers may suggest that management screwed this up all by itself.

> Programmers are reluctant to test code, because (1) they find it just
>   boring, and because (2) if they don't test code, it looks like they
>   deliver the feature faster.

Well, management does screw up occasionally, right? It seems that pressure has been built on delivering features quickly, and this has pervaded the culture a bit. Cutting corners and dropping tests go hand-in-hand when under excessive pressure to deliver, unfortunately.

Experienced programmers would go a long way over how tests are **worth the time**, rather than complaining that they eat up their time and they don't get to deliver value, as they say. I am in the devil's advocate position of having to give the simple explanation that the programmers are relatively inexperienced, but also, the entire system they are juggling with is not that complex, so they have not had too much trouble yet, to really feel the value of proper automated tests.

There is only one suggestion here I would be in position to give and this is to **strive** to make the developers **feel the actual value of tests** at all costs. Also, while at it, keep the external testers **and** compose proper automated tests to the extent possible. If the output is not **too** complicated, safety-critical, etc... the company could *probably* do without the external testers, but that always depends on the details.

Comment: Some excellent points here. However, that last paragraph feels totally out-of-place, and does not add any value to an otherwise excellent answer, imho.

Comment: yes the condom analogy seems a bit awkward out of place. Other than that, one correction " **good** tests don't randomly fail on good software". For example, if you don't consider concurrency in your tests and your application you may end up with tests randomly failing if you run multiple tests in parallel for instance. That would however be a sign that either you need to redesign your tests, how you run them or even your software because it has a concurrency bug.

Comment: It's fair to say the author should have stopped sooner.

Comment: It's fair to acknowledge a failed attempt at humor! :-X I am removing the last paragraph and integrating the correction suggested by Frank! Indeed, tests also have to be **good**.

Answer (score 9):

Don't just assume you're right about over reliance on integration testing. You're pushing for the wrong things. Be very careful about driving people to measurable results vs actual results.

> Measuring, per person, how many tickets are reopened by the testers (and sharing the results to the whole team).

I’m sorry but this is just dumb. The programmers job isn't done when code is in the hands of a tester. Counting how many times code goes back and forth between them against the programer is counter productive. You want programmers engaged with testers. Don't punish them for doing it. Good programmers cheer on their testers. They don't hide from them.

> Giving congratulation to the persons who performed the best, i.e. those who have the least tickets being reopened.

This is not a good measurement of best. You're rewarding those who can hide their bugs, not those who work to see them eliminated.

> Spend time pair programming with those who performed the worst, trying to understand why are they so reluctant to test their code, and showing them that it's not that difficult.

Everyone who runs their code is testing their code. When people don't understand how they're being judged the smart ones don't even try to guess. They just quickly submit to the judgement and hope to learn something useful from the result. We have a fancy term for this behavior. It's called agile.

Now please don't take that to mean I don't like pair programming. I love it. I've learned more sitting with fellow coders banging away on a problem then from any book or blog. Can't wait for this covid thing to go away so I can get back it doing it.

But it's not pair programming if all you do is preach. If you do this, shut up and listen to your partner. You may learn something and find your problem isn't what you think it is.

> Explaining that it's much faster to solve a problem right now, than to wait for several days until the feature gets tested.

Well here's your problem. It shouldn't take several days to test a feature. Think of code like cement. The longer it sits, the harder it is to move. Get me tester feedback faster. Preferably before I start thinking about other features.

The longer it takes to catch a bug the more expensive it is to fix.

> Explaining that testers do system tests only, and the lack of unit tests make it difficult to pinpoint the exact location of the problem.

Stop explaining and do **peer unit testing**. It shows them what you want. Programmers communicate best with code. This lets them do that.

Works like this: I write a unit test. I write production code that passes my unit test. You peer review the code, notice something hinky, and you write a unit test that proves hinkyness. You send your unit test to me, I look it over and either make it pass or we talk about what the real requirement should be. Do peer unit testing and your weak unit testers will learn from your stronger ones. Strangely enough, the strong ones will also learn from the weak ones.

Oh and you can do this when you pair program. Makes the whole thing go fast.

Speaking of requirements, if the integration tester isn't part of the discussion about the requirements, and which ones are testable, before this coding started you're out of your mind. They make the call on which requirements are integration testable. Coders should know how this shook out before they even start on a design.

You send code to integration testers after it's been through peer review & peer testing. Now two coders have picked this over early and both of them should be rooting for the testers to find any remaining bugs. They shouldn't be trying to hide them. They should be openly reporting anything that might help the integration tester find them.

It's not programmers vs testers. It's all of us against the bugs.

So stop rewarding people for creating untestable code.

Answer (score 5):

I'm firmly in the 100% automated coverage camp. I think it actually helps me go faster in the long term, and I *hate* having things kicked back to me from a tester.

That being said, if people hate doing automated tests, you need to provide an incentive to not have to write them. If they think they can still maintain quality without automated tests, let them prove it. I would require automated tests for any bugs that are kicked back to them from testers, and make them optional otherwise. In other words, they need to write a test that fails if the reported bug is present, then show that it passes with their fix, as a prerequisite to getting it retested by the testers.

What I hope would happen, is the sloppiest programmers will end up having to write the most tests, which should encourage them to take more care. Code that is the easiest to break will end up with the best coverage. People will likely start preemptively writing tests for things that are difficult to test manually, and doing more thorough manual tests for tests that are more difficult to automate. Hopefully there will also be some investment in making tests easier to write and run. Very little will change for programmers who are already careful.

Comment: I like this idea of automatically balancing tests toward where the most problems occur, because I think it could help with a situation I've often seen - lots of tests, but they're only testing the trivial cases, so they don't catch much.  I think it does need management buy-in though, because this will often add extra time taken at the point a feature is heading toward release.

Answer (score 4):

A couple of points I'm not really seeing in the other answers.

The skill sets for development and testing may overlap **but** some people make great testers, and sometimes they're not the same people that make great developers. As a developer, a good QA department *is* worth its weight in gold; forcing me to do *all* the tests myself, especially in an environment where *someone else's code* might change the behaviour of a web page *between when I test it and when the combined set of changes goes live* is ... the opposite. So, if you have a constant stream of changes, testing the finished result *after it's been merged* is quite a bit more important.

A developer will likely be able to tell you *what* needs testing, what could go wrong, and so on. Listen to them.

Another point I'm seeing in the OP is that at some point, after your developers had got used to using one testing framework, there was a decision to switch to another, which boasts on its website of reducing the volume of integration tests, and so on.

You **didn't** mention the reasons this decision was made, nor whether any training or learning time was set aside for this change. Were they expected to learn this new framework *on top of* continuing to work at the expected pace on feature development, bug fixing, and so on?

Comment: I agree with this. Testing is a specialism. In the simple cases I could be both bricklayer and dynamite man to an adequate degree, but there comes a point where the person who knows how best to put it up is not the one who knows how best to bring it down.

Answer (score 3):

Consider taking this up in the *Project Management* thread.

But also – simply tell them that their work will not be accepted unless it is accompanied by automated tests.  "Yes, this *is* part of your job."  The external testers are there only to keep you honest.

As a lifetime software developer myself *(as well as a consulting project manager),* I can directly speak to the number of times when I feel that "my a*s was saved" by the tests that I wrote, even of my own code that no one else would work on, as I was building it.  I *frequently* "failed to get it right."  And I was sometimes astonished when an earlier test suddenly started failing.  I found-and-fixed one "gotcha!" after another ... before it had a chance.  And in this way I built layer upon layer of code *knowing* that it was correct.

Get management support behind you that "it's not accepted until it's tested, and we reserve the right to reject your tests."

Comment: It seems to me you're failing to appreciate the likely role of management in producing the problem. Originally it was said that programmers were grumbling, but not that they were failing to test to a high standard. The overall theme is a familiar one: management try to cut costs by cutting corners, then quality falls.

Answer (score 3):

You can encourage developers not to "overly rely" on testers by
focusing on the results you're really trying to achieve (presumably
features that balance the cost of development with the value the
company gets from them being deployed at a certain quality level) and
letting the developers decide how much to rely on the testers in order
to achieve this goal. In other words, unless you're part of the
development team, you're trying to manage something that the
development team should be managing.

#### Fixing "Done"

The first thing you need to do is fix your definition of "done." You
say that developers,

> ...would sometimes mark features as done without even actually
>   [checking] if they work in a browser: since testers will catch the
>   mistakes, why bother?

First, redefine "done" as, "the change is ready to go out into
production, for use by real customers." Second, make each developer
responsible for management of the process that gets any particular
change to the "done" stage. That includes ensuring that whatever
testing the developer considers necessary is completed, whether that
be by writing and running automated tests, sending code and test
instructions to human testers and reviewing the results, or anything
else they can think of.

If a change is found to be defective in some way after the developer
has declared it "done," that's the time to sit down with the developer
and do some review. This review should be between the developer and
one or more senior members of the development team. (It might or might
not also include someone from the product owner side; see below.) This
review should not be confrontational and certainly should not start
out by assuming something was done wrongly, but examine the impact of
the released (or about to be released, if you caught it in time)
defect and consider what cost-effective measures could have been taken
to avoid that happening, i.e., what the developer (and the development
team) should change to improve things. (The answer may well be,
"Nothing. The cost of preventing all or most things like this is more
than the cost living with them.")

The product owner in such meetings, if present, is not there to push
the team for technical or procedural changes but for two other things:
1. to provide information about the cost of the negative business
impact from the release (or estimated cost, if the defect got caught
in time), and 2. to evaluate whether or not the product owner wants to
pay additional costs to prevent this kind of problem. (E.g., the
developers say, "we can reduce the incidence of this kind of thing by
50% but it will slow development by 5%"; the product owner can then
decide whether the increased quality at release is worth the slower
rate of getting features rolled out.)

#### Developers Manage Testing

Sending changes out to human testers is, at a high level, not much
different from writing automated tests. There's some sort of script
for the testers or test system to follow (even if it's a simple as,
"go to this URL and tell me what you think") and the developer
evaluates the results to decide whether she's done or she needs to do
more work (be that changing code or running more tests).

This script needs to be kept somewhere where it can be reviewed by
other developers at (or in preparation for) the meetings I described
above. And the history of changes to it needs to be kept as well, so
that e.g. if a developer removed something from it (perhaps because
she added automated tests to cover something that was problematic or
taking too long for the human testers to do) the review can examine
that decision. (Personally, I would usually keep this information in
the source code repo itself, in text or markdown files, but the
developers should do whatever works well for them and the test team.)

The initial script would probably include the story from the product
owner, instructions about how to set up anything needed for testing
that bit of code, and any other notes the developer finds useful to
throw in.

As with anything, developers not experienced with this will probably
need some support from others in the development team. You wouldn't
expect a developer with little experience in unit testing to be able
to write good unit tests right off the bat, or even figure out what
needs to be tested; the same goes for managing manual testing.

But the developers need to keep their eye on the goal here: to be able
to declare something as "done" with the meaning that they think it will
pass all acceptance tests done by the product owner, or that would be
done by the product owner if he didn't trust the developers so much,
and even any tests that the product owner might think of after the
developer's got the story and started coding it.

#### Acceptance

There's something I somewhat elided above, which is that there really
are two "done" stages, under the control of separate teams. The first
is the development team's "done" stage, which means "I expect that
this will pass all acceptance tests," as mentioned above. The second
is the product owner's "I accept this change; let's release it." How
much work the product owner does on this side depends on how good a
job the development team is doing. Where a development team has proven
themselves very reliable at interpreting the requirements and writing
code that meets them, the product owner may do minimal testing. Where
the development team is not doing such a great job at this, the
product owner will have to more verification.

Where you currently stand on this spectrum is not too important: what
is important is that, when acceptance testing fails, the development
team reviews how it failed (i.e., why they incorrectly felt is was
"done" when it wasn't) and develops systems to prevent future similar
failures at acceptance testing. Improving this in any particular
instance may be a purely internal technical matter for the development
team to deal with, or some failures may be due to communications
problems between the product owner and the development team, in which
case they need to work together to figure out how to fix that.

#### Summary

Writing automated tests and sending code off to a test team are simply
two different methods of acheiving the goal of ensuring a change is of
sufficient quality to release. They're almost invariably used
together, and the decision about how much of each to use needs to fall
to the developer making the change, because it's intimately affected
by how she chooses to write her code. So she should be manging that,
and needs whatever support is necessary to get good at managing that.

Answer (score 2):

Reviews may work better in that environment.

As a developer I feel the same. Writing tests is dead boring (particularly unit tests). And they are not always effective (particularly unit tests). It depends on the type of logic you write and on the kind of input you get. 100% specified requirements are not that common in my experience so what would your tests prove, really? Requiring people to write unit tests just because can be demotivating. So can shaming people who produce the most "bugs" (they may well be the same ones producing the most value).

Peer pressure is more effective. You have to get used to one another and this may hurt a bit but in the end you will have a team. You will not get a team by imposing external rules that are not supported by the people that have to follow them.

I would even suggest to ditch the off-shore test guys altogether. I mean, why would I try hard to deliver flawless behavior when I am not trusted to do so anyway and there is another layer of verification going over my work anyway? Apparently this is the way we work, right? While they are there, let them make my life a little easier and find the loose ends for me to fix, so I don't have to put too much effort in it.

If that safety net weren't there... I would be more careful. I would feel respected and responsible. With an attitude like "you are going to deliver crap so we will have everything you produce scrutinized", I would not feel inclined to try very hard.

Comment: I personally think that effective testing depends on a significant body of specialist skill and knowledge, and the inclination to be involved with it differs between individuals (just as with any sort of skill or area of knowledge). The architect who designs buildings does not necessarily want to be the person who builds the scale models and builds individual wind tunnels to test them - even if he would be content to turn his hand to any of these tasks, to turn his hand to them all in one project involves too much complexity for a single mind.

Comment: I know that I am a good developer, but I really suck at testing, especially exploratory testing. I love delivering high quality software and I actually feel good if a good tester finds it hard to discover a flaw in my software. For me, it is a good thing that my software gets additional scrutiny by a test team before it is released into the wild. It might also matter that I work in industries where a bug in the wild costs the company real money and goodwill as products may have to be recalled for repairs.

Comment: Just to clarify: You're saying testing is boring for you, as a developer, and you're also recommending getting rid of QA. So that means you're recommending no testing whatsoever and you trust there will be high quality because developers will just try harder (and review well)?

Comment: Testing (particularly unit testing) is not supposed to *always* be effective at catching bugs, because there may not always be bugs to catch, testing well / writing good tests is hard and testing absolutely every possible thing that can happen is just not realistic. It's supposed to catch bugs *sometimes*, provide peace of mind that your code is working as intended, make it easier track down bugs earlier and become a habit so you do it when needed. Also, you shouldn't *need* external requirements to inform tests (although it helps). If you know what the code does, you should know what to test.

Comment: @Dukeling, when you say *"If you know what the code does, you should know what to test"*, I think that's precisely the problem. For many, the purpose of testing is because they *aren't sure* they know what the code does - if they did, testing would be needless in their circumstances. In larger, longer-lived codebases, tests are not altogether about finding current bugs, but mitigating the risk of future bugs that arise from unintended breaking changes maybe 10 or 20 years down the line, or mitigating the risk of bugs from large teams who don't all fully understand the whole.

Comment: Unit testing isn't primarily supposed to verify overall feature requirements from an outside stakeholder! That's what system and integration tests are primarily for. Unit tests verify and document your (developer) understanding of how a small unit should behave! To avoid bugs before they happen at implementation or a later refactoring time. You can only refactor fast - especially foreign code - if you are certain you don't break anything. Encapsulation helps with that, so do unit tests.

Comment: As an improvement suggestion: I see one valid point here, that social pressure may help (and reviews as one way to do that). That could be expanded on. The rest seems like a weird "I can do everything best" attitude that flies in the face of all practical experience in how large software is typically built (are there exceptions, yes, but uncommon). Maybe it's not meant that way. So, I'd focus on the peer pressure part, how to implement it and less on the why you feel QA should go away and unit tests are not helping. That peer pressure can btw. also be put into place to push for unit tests^^

Comment: @Frank The question is not whether unit tests are good or bad. I do not dispute their value. I do claim their is a place for them and one should not create them as a rule ("thou must create unit tests"). The OP wants to know how developers tick (as if he isn't one himself, the guy writes the best answers on this forum and asks a silly question like this, anyway). So I painted him a picture of the mind set of the typical developer. This is how it works. I am not saying it is desirable, it is just a fact that if you take away responsibilities from people, they WILL feel less responsible.

Answer (score 2):

Our organization solved the problem of developers never actually testing their changes themselves by making that part of the process:

1. Giving a change to testing requires that you provide documentation of your changes.
2. Documentation must be made using the standardized template.
3. That template includes the following mandatory sections:

   - What was the reason for the change?
   - What was changed?
   - A "Functionality Test" where the developer does a basic test of the change, documented its execution and results with screenshots in a way which shows that the goal of the change was achieved. This test is not expected to be as thorough as a test performed by the actual QA team. It is just supposed to demonstrate that it now appears to work as far as the developer is concerned.

That way every developer is forced to run their changed code at least once.

Answer (score 1):

You need a **"definition of done"**

Generally accepted 'definitions of done' include not only working code, but working unit tests, and documentation. Until those things are completed, **the task is not done** and the code cannot and **should not** be released to the testing department or god forbid, live.

While you'll often find the concept under the Agile/Scrum umbrella, that working framework isn't necessary to implement this idea.

https://www.scruminc.com/definition-of-done/

https://www.agilealliance.org/glossary/definition-of-done/

The testers are there to catch the things you didn't think of, weird use cases, or things honestly missed.

Comment: Plus, I think, a review of the code and tests by another developer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the policy went from one extreme to the other. I've never seen working in practice a test coverage of 100%. The trade off between the amount of time and detail required to write a test for a function and the benefit of the test itself is usually very variable. Mandating in a blunt manner a 100% test coverage without considering the trade off will eventually force the developers to take more time than needed to write some tests.

A flexible approach would be better. Require a minimum of test coverage and tell the developers to try and judge how difficult would be to write the test for a function. However another person who is not the developer himself should do some review, check which functions are subject to frequent changes or have such complex requirements that they could be broken easily and flag those functions as the ones that need a test no matter what.

Another thing that would help is finding the developer most skilled with the testing tools and ask him to develop some templates for the most difficult part. Often finding how to build the mocks around a particular function really takes a lot of time. A set of patterns/solution close at hand would save a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

There's a very simple solution.

You call a meeting with your developers. In that meeting you tell them: "We have a problem with our process right now. It seems that at the moment, the code that is submitted very often does not work properly. That causes QA to spend too much time writing bug reports, and then costs development time fixing those bugs. We had the problem previously that development was extremely high quality, but at huge cost. We need to get more to a point in the middle, where the developers spend a bit more time to make sure there are not too many problems passed to QA, so we can work more efficiently overall".

Some answers are too focussed on the difficulty to find the best point. That's not required. You had a point at one extreme which was inefficient, you have a point at the other extreme now which is inefficient, going further to the middle will be an improvement. Don't ignore an improvement just because you cannot find the optimal point.

Answer (score 0):

You have just answered your questions, when have the two topics been published:
"Programmers are reluctant to test code, because (1) they find it just boring, and because (2) if they don't test code, it looks like they deliver the feature faster."
What does it mean? How the delivery is done, if there are no tests, which are planned?
Any project/module can be delivered (even put to a GIT) only after Maven or Gradle or whatever else has executed all the tests along the build. What is an input of the development of a unit? Analysts or architects must provide a list of cases, which must be subject to tests for a component, or in the worst case, testing engineers (who are responsible for tests) first put tests into the repository and developers get them upon pull request. Maven/Gradle will do the work. Besides, before delivery is done, it HAS(!!) to pass a code review with first attention to the test. And only then, after verifying the consistency of the tests, changes can be merged with the branch, which is used for the industrial build. What is done faster, if there is no proof of work:- bugs and problems?
The rule is simple. No tests- no delivery, no work is not done! That's all.

"Spend time pair programming with those who performed the worst, trying to understand why are they so reluctant to test their code, and showing them that it's not that difficult."
Really, XP's element as Pair Programming is not dedicated to displaying ABC to developers, which are reluctant to do a part of the work, which they are paid for. Testing - is not only testing, it is a part (an important) of their work, that must be in the definition of a position. The approach you have mentioned- is a spent time on the highest chance of bugs.  Your environment, including DevOps, must be built in accordance with the principle: only a component, which passes all the PREDEFINED tests is to go. Otherwise- it is not delivered.

Answer (score -2):

You'll need to go back to developers doing testing.

Where I work, every change pushed out by our team is tested by two other people on the team. The originating developer provides a test plan, and the two peer testers run the test, any other tests they feel like running, and do code review as well.

If it passes this, then our QA department gets a hold of it.

The only drawback I've encountered with this strategy is that some of our developers would be doomed if their lives ever depend on their ability to write clearly.